# set up different clickable part image android

Tags: android, image, view, onclicklistener

Im working with android about image and onclick listener. The purpose of my app is to monitor the area that user clicks on the screen. For example, I have a picture containing a rectangular and a circle. Assume that the color of the whole picture is brown(wood). So when I click on the rectangular, the color of rectangle will change to yellow. When I click on the one part of the picture, the color of that part will change its color, but other parts do not change. So, Im thinking about the solution for this app. Do I have to cut this picture separately and put them into the screen by using relative review? Or is there any other way to do this(Set up a coordination system)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to cut this picture separately and put them into the screen by using relative review. For example two `ImageView` with your backgound.

Answer (score 0):

You can slse the image as recommeded by the other post, or overlay the image with a RelitiveLayout with specific sized buttons (background = @android/color/transparent)